# What scripting/programming languages are default on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, script, code

I was wondering what programming or scripting languages come pre-installed on OSX? Particularly programs that can be run from the command line.

I'm planning on parsing some CSS, and outputting an html page. I've done it in python before, but I would like to make sure it's transferrable to others in my organization.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OS X doesn't come with any compilers built-in. It has a number of scripting languages though:

- Python (2.7.2)
- Perl (5.12.4)
- Ruby (1.8.7p358)
- PHP (5.3.15)
- Bash (3.2)
- Zsh (4.3.11)
- AWK
- Tcl/Tk (8.5.9 and 8.4.19)
- …

The listed versions are included in OS X Mountain Lion (v10.8), but some version of each of these has been included in OS X since at least v10.3.

Comment: What about Vimscript and JS? :)

Comment: MacBook Air (M1) comes with Python 2.7.16 and not, as I did expect, 2.7.18 ([April 20, 2020](https://www.python.org/downloads/ "Download Python | Python.org")). According to Wikipedia, it was released in [17 November 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air#Fourth_generation_(M1) "MacBook Air - Wikipedia"). Do you happen to know what the reason is?